# Excel remove duplicate string, by compare with another cells?

Tags: excel, duplicates

[image]

as mentioned above "Cell C", contains "Cell A & B"'s text.
I want to filter, like below screen shot.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me at any point. Are you looking for something like that: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C2,A2,""),B2,"")`?

Comment: Nope, my cell C value contains of cell A+B+C data, where as cell C have unique data. I need it separate. is any simplified method I want to do it for around 1Lac records.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Still, I don't get what you are really looking for...

Comment: firstly very thankful to you,for following up. I am not familier with excel. I want to split the data in cell 3, where as, I have same content cell 1 & 2. If you see in screenshot 1,"Cell C" contains cell A & B data and C's unique data. So, I need cell C as only it's unique data. Please write me back if still to give clarity I will come up with some examples...

Comment: then the formula provided in the first coment should work... (have you tried it?)

Comment: I tried it, little confusion. It is removing column B data, but not column A data. If understand correctly we are replacing empty string right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101520/discussion-between-venu-gopal-reddy-and-dirk-reichel).

Answer (score 1):

As a short VBA solution, you could use this:

```
Sub test()
  With ActiveSheet
    Dim ColAB As Variant, ColC As Variant, i As Long
    ColAB = Intersect(.Columns("A:B"), .UsedRange).Value
    ColC = Intersect(.Columns(3), .UsedRange).Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(ColC, 1)
      ColC(i, 1) = Trim(Replace(Replace(ColC(i, 1), ColAB(i, 1), ""), ColAB(i, 2), ""))
    Next
    .Range("C1:C" & UBound(ColC)).Value = ColC
  End With
End Sub
```

But try it with a copy first (you can't undo it)

still, the `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(C2,A2,""),B2,"")`-formula should work... if not, then there may be a difference in the text (and the search string can't be found)